# How to run imported image in Docker.io?

Tags: node.js, docker

*I have tried [hello world node.js with docker](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/examples/nodejs_web_app/#nodejs-web-app). I have created an image & container. I exported the container using*

```
docker export $container_ID > container_ID.tar
```

**Q. How to run it after importing it back ?**

```
docker import - <user-name>/node-hello < container_ID.tar
docker run -p 49610:8080 -d <user-name>/node-hello
```

> Error: create: No command specified

---

I found a a git hub issue [import error](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/1826)

solution given here is :

```
docker run -p 49610:8080 -d <user-name>/node-hello /someCommandToRun.sh
```

I tried adding Dockerfile commands like (ADD ./src;cd ./src;npm install ; CMD['node','./src/index.js'])
but the image fails with exit 127

**Q. What is the command to give the node-hello-world image to run ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`docker run` takes a command to run as its final argument. The command must exist in the container. For example, `docker run <image> bash` will run `bash` in the container and then immediately exit. To have an interactive bash shell in the container use `docker run -t -i <image> bash`.

`docker run` does not take Dockerfile commands like `ADD` and `CMD`. To use a Dockerfile, put all your commands in a file called `Dockerfile`, then use `docker build -t="some tag name" .` to build the image.

You should begin with the [Getting Started](https://www.docker.io/gettingstarted/) guide to better understand Docker.

Comment: There is still an actual bug at the URL you specified.  Exported images do not keep their metadata or aren't loaded properly. In version 0.9.1 at least.

Comment: `docker run` does not require a command if a CMD with an executable has been specified in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 5):

**Q. How to run it after importing it back ?**

Ans: `docker run -p 49610:8080 -d <user-name>/node-hello /someCommandToRun.sh`

**Q. What is the command to give the node-hello-world image to run ?**

Ans :`docker run -p 49610:8080 -d <user-name>/node-hello node /src/index.js`